# Match-zero-or-more operator in shell globbing

Tags: shell, regular-expression, wildcards

I'm stuck in a quite trivial problem here: how can I make the `*` symbol in bash mean *zero or more*, like it does in tools such as `sed`?

For example, `ak*` should match any file whose name consists entirely of an `a` followed by zero or more `k`s. Its expansion would include `a`, `ak`, `akk`, and `akkk`, but not `akc`.

I have already tried `unsetopt sh_glob` in zsh and `set -o noglob` in bash; they did not produce the desired behavior.

Comment: Does it have to be glob?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, I just wanted to point out what I have already tried. I had changed the title to reflect that.

Comment: The word you are looking for is "globbing" or "wildcards" (latter might depends on the context).

Comment: Um, the regex `ak*` in `sed` would totally match `akc` (and also just `a`).

Comment: @thrig, `^ak+$` or `^akk*$` would work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Except for `ksh93`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239025), none of the usual shells have regular expressions with the same syntax as sed, awk, etc. that can be used for matching files.

Ksh93, bash and zsh have regular expressions with a different syntax that's backward compatible with globs:

- `?` matches any single character (like `.` in the usual regexp syntax)
- `[…]` matches a character set in mostly the same way
- `*(FOO)` matches any number of occurrences of `FOO` (like `(FOO)*` in the usual regexp syntax)
- similarly `+(FOO)` matches one or more occurrences, and `?(FOO)` matches zero or one occurrence
- `@(FOO|BAR)` matches either `FOO` or `BAR`
- Matches apply to the whole string, not a substring; if you want a substring, put `*` at the beginning and at the end

This syntax needs to be activated with `shopt -s extglob` in bash and with `setopt ksh_glob` in zsh. So in bash you'd write

```
shopt -s extglob
ls a*(k)
```

See also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Ksh93, zsh and bash can do regular expression matching with extended regular expressions (basically the syntax of awk) on strings, with the `=~` operator of the `[[ … ]]` construct. This isn't convenient for listing files though, but if you really want it, it can be done.

```
shopt -s dotglob  # <<< include dot files, for bash
setopt globdots   # <<< include dot files, for zsh
FIGNORE='@(.|..)' # <<< include dot files, for ksh
for x in *; do
  if [[ $x =~ ^ak*$ ]]; then
    …
  fi
done
```

Comment: A simple answer like `ls a*(k)` would already get you an accepted answer, so thank you for taking your time to make this thorough answer.

Comment: Now, are you sure that your third bullet is correct? `a(k)` gives syntax error, therefore I suppose that (foo) alone is not the whole syntax for that part.

Comment: @Kira I was confused by this, too. [Looking at the answer's source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/e093f268-f0e5-452f-8e27-7afa69229242/view-source), though, it seems that Gilles meant `*(foo)` rather than `(foo)`. I've [proposed an edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/24552) to fix up the formatting.

Comment: `ksh93` globs can use regular expressions: `echo ~(E:ak*)` for ERE.

Answer (score 8):

`ls ak{k,}` will display files beginning with `ak` followed either by another `k` or nothing.

```
$ touch ak akk akc
$ ls -l ak{k,}
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas 0 Oct 27 10:30 ak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cas cas 0 Oct 27 10:30 akk
```

globs aren't regexps, but there's more to them than just `*` and `?`.

If you want to use regexps to find matching filenames, you can use the `find` command:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './ak+$' 
./ak
./akk
```

The `-maxdepth 1` option limits the search to just the current directory (no subdirectories will be searched)

If you want case-insensitive searches, use `-iregex` rather than `-regex`.

There are numerous methods for using the files found by `find` in other commands.  For example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './ak+$' -ls
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './ak+$' -exec ls -ld {} +
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './ak+$' -print0 | xargs -0r ls -ld
ls -ld $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './ak+$')
```

The last example is prone to various failure modes, including 1. not coping with white-space etc in filenames, 2. command-line length limits.  not recommended.

Comment: I exactly have this in mind but i think OP wants a more generic solution that is not bound to any certain filenames..

Comment: Your answer is a bit too specific, I want to have a arbitrary number of `k`'s. I'm going to edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @heemayl, as with regexps, globs need to be crafted for the exact circumstances as required.  @kira, see `man 7 glob` - unlike regex, glob doesn't have a zero-or-more or 1-or-more modifier.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` the syntax you can use is:
        `ls a+(k)`
This depends on the `bash` `shopt` shell option `extglob` being enabled.  On Ubuntu 14.04 GNU/Linux, this appears to be enabled by default.

This is how it works:

```
$ shopt extglob
extglob         on
$ ls
ak  akc  akd  akk  akkk  akkkk
$ ls a+(k)
ak  akk  akkk  akkkk
$ shopt -u extglob
$ shopt extglob
extglob         off
$ ls a+(k)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$
```

From the Bash Manual:

> +(pattern-list)
>
> > Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.
> >
> > a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a ‘|’.

See this in the Bash Manual at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching.

Answer (score 2):

A few options depending on the shell:

```
$ touch a akk aka
$ ksh -c 'echo a*(k)'
a akk
$ zsh -o kshglob -o nobareglobqual -c 'echo a*(k)'
a akk
```

(`nobareglobqual` for that trailing `(k)` not to be taken as a glob qualifier here)

```
$ bash -O extglob -c 'echo a*(k)'
a akk

$ zsh -o extendedglob -c 'echo ak#'
a akk
```

`zsh`'s `#` is the equivalent of regexp `*`.

`ksh93` can also use several types of regular expressions in its globs:

```
$ ksh93 -c 'echo ~(E:ak*)' # extended RE
a akk
$ ksh93 -c 'echo ~(P:ak*)' # perl-like RE
a akk
$ ksh93 -c 'echo ~(X:ak*)' # AT&T augmented RE
a akk
$ ksh93 -c 'echo @(~(E)ak*)' # alternative syntax
a akk
```